SOQL with Field Permissions
I'm using the query in this first answer to this question and getting strange results.
The results from the FieldPermissions query is returning a name of X00e4x000... which, as I understand it, is a profile ID with an X in front of it. Yet when I look at that profile, I don't see access granted to the ActionPlan or Asset object, but yet it is returned in the query results from FieldPermissions.
When I query as a user with that profile and try to query the Asset or ActionPlan object I get an error - as expected since I haven't granted access to those objects - but yet they come back in the query with PermissionsRead and PermissionsEdit as true.
Why are they being returned when they're not in the permission set?
